# Re-try previous stage in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have two stages in my Jenkins pipeline, `functional` and `report`.

[image: Jenkins Pipeline]

`functional` execute a series of tests in parallel.
`report` analyses the results.

I have a check in `report`, so see if the number of failed tests is less than 3.

If this check is true, how can I jump back and re-execute the entire `functional` stage programmatically? In Blue Ocean you can re-run this manually via the UI. I am looking for a way to do this in Groovy.

We are using declarative pipelines.

```
if (failedTests < 3) {
 // jump back to `functional` stage
}
```

The functional stage is just a standard `stage` within our Jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving the stage to an external function. Something like below.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Wrapper') {
      steps {
        script {
            functionalStage()
            reportStage()
         
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

def functionalStage() {
    stage("Functional Stage") {
        echo "Running tests"
    }
}

def reportStage() {
    stage("Report Stage") {
        if (failedTests < 3) {
          functionalStage()
        }
    }
}
```